# Why doesn't this function execute anything?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have tried different browsers and even different editors but none of them work and I don't what I have done wrong. It doesn't execute a thing. Can y'all please help me?

```
let number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() *10) +1); 
let number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() *10) +1);
  function sum(number1, number2) {
    return number1 + number2; 
  }
  console.log(sum);
```

Comment: You need to actually call the function. Something like this: `console.log(sum(number1, number2));`

Comment: Your code does not call the function. `console.log(sum(number1, number2))`

Comment: you have defined the function, just call it with numbers

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user is asking help for a basic programming skill, such as to how to call a function.

Answer (score 1):

**You're not invoking it, but only passing a reference to it**, hence the `console` will `log` only an `Object (function)` when you do it like that.

Instead, you need to invoke the function with the `functionName()` syntax, i.e.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

console.log(sum) // Object (function) [wrong]
console.log(sum(2, 2)) // 4 [correct]
```

To ultra-simplify it for you, think of it this way

```js
functionName // references the function
functionName() // runs the functions
```

Answer (score 1):

in Your Case Thing is That You Successfully Created Function but we need to call / invoke that function too. for execution . when you write **sum** that means you just initiate that function But when you write **sum()** than your browsers javascript recognize that i need to execute this function , there have many types of function like no argument with return , with argument with return ..... , but in your case what you need to do is pass argument in function like **sum(number1,number2)** .

```js
let number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() *10) +1); 
let number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() *10) +1);
  function sum(number1, number2) {
    return number1 + number2; 
  }
  console.log(sum(number1,number2));
```